# Save HTML File to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, plotly

After converting a Plotly graph to an HTML Page by this code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")


plotly.offline.plot(fig , filename = 'filename.html', auto_open=False)
```

How can I store this HTML Page on an S3 bucket?

I tried this code:

```
fig.write_html('testPage.html', auto_play=False)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 Read-only file system: 'testPage.html'
```

Comment: You can use boto3 (with the right credentials) python package to store the file in AWS S3.

Comment: Hi @AnthonyB. Could you show us an example of that?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are running this into a lambda:

```
import boto3
import plotly
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y="GOOG")

file_name = 'testPage.html'
fig.write_html('/tmp/'+file_name, auto_play=False)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/'+file_name, 'my-bucket', file_name)
```

Make sure the lambda has the right permission in place to upload the file into the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest code examples of all AWS SDKs, including Python, look at the new AWS Code Library here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html

You will find  hundreds of code examples in many different programming languages. Included in this doc is how to perform Amazon S3 operations using the **AWS SDK for Python**.

The Code Library is not the old Code Catelog - its the replacement.

UPDATE

Your code to upload an object using Python SDK is here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_s3_code_examples.html

See this topic.

[image]

Comment: Hi smac2020, thanks for your answer. I tried this code: fig.write_html('testPage.html', auto_play=False) , but I'm getting this error :  Read-only file system: 'testPage.html'  . I've updated my question. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: See my update - the code you want is shown in the red area,.